# How to retrieve recursively any files with a specific extensions in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

For a specific folder, I need to list all files with extension `.js` even if nested in subfolders at any level.

The result for the output console should be a list of file names with no extension line by line to be easily copy and pasted in another application.

At the moment I am trying this, but in output console I get several meta information and not a simple list.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\xx\x-Recurse -File | sort length –Descending
```

Could you please provide me some hints?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

If sorting by Length is not a necessity, you can use the `-Name` parameter to have `Get-ChildItem` return just the name, then use `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` to remove the path and extension:

```psh
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.js -Recurse -File -Name| ForEach-Object {
    [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_)
}
```

If sorting by length is desired, drop the `-Name` parameter and output the `BaseName` property of each `FileInfo` object. You can pipe the output (in both examples) to `clip`, to copy it into the clipboard:

```psh
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.js -Recurse -File| Sort-Object Length -Descending | ForEach-Object {
    $_.BaseName
} | clip
```

If you want the full path, but without the extension, substitute `$_.BaseName` with:

```psh
$_.FullName.Remove($_.FullName.Length - $_.Extension.Length)
```

Comment: thanks for your great answer, could you please help me with the last scenario.. I would need the full path, but WITH the extension [similarly at your last example]... how could I make it? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @GibboK Just use `$_.FullName`, that's the path to the file

Comment: great thanks, just last thing if you have time :).. now my resulting string is like 'C:\Projects\x\trunk\www\c\n\b\file.js' I wound need to truncate the first part until \n\ folder..... with final result as 'n\b\file.js' any idea what could be used? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @GibboK use $_.FullName.Substring()

Comment: Is it realistic to get the file sizes? `ls` would do that ….

Comment: I feel insane to be the only one asking this but, coming from bash, surely there must be a shorter way of doing this? How am I supposed to discover this as an option?
In bash, I believe the equivalent is `find . -name *.js`

Comment: @escapecharacter FWIW `ls . *.js -re -file` will do the same in PowerShell. You can see all existing aliases with `Get-Alias` (or `alias`, or `gal`)

Answer (score 15):

The simple option is to use the `.Name` property of the `FileInfo` item in the pipeline and then remove the extension:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\code\" -Filter *.js -r | % { $_.Name.Replace( ".js","") }
```

Answer (score 12):

There are two methods for filtering files: [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) using an Wildcard, or using a Regular Expression (Regex).

**Warning:** The globbing method has the drawback that it also matches files which should not be matched, like `*.jsx`.

```ps
# globbing with Wildcard filter 
# the error action prevents the output of errors
# (ie. directory requires admin rights and is inaccessible)
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter '*.js' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' 

# filter by Regex
Where-Object { $_.Name -Match '.*\.js$' }
```

You then can sort by name or filesize as needed:

```ps
# sort the output 
Sort-Object -PropertyName 'Length'
```

Format it a simple list of path and filename:

```ps
# format output
Format-List -Property ('Path','Name')
```

To remove the file extension, you can use an select to map the result:

```ps
Select-Item { $_.Name.Replace( ".js", "") }
```

Putting it all together, there is also a very short version, which you should not use in scripts, because it's hardly readable:

```ps
ls -r | ? { $_.Name -matches '.*\.js' } | sort Length | % { $_.Name.Replace( ".js", "") | fl
```

Comment: The last command (`ls -r | ? { $_.Name -m '.*\.js' } | sort Length | % { $_.Name.Replace( ".js", "") | fl`) cannot cope with the `m` flag.

Answer (score 6):

If you like brevity, you can remove the ForEach-Object and quotes. `-Path` defaults to the current directory so you can omit it

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.js -Recurse).BaseName | Sort length -Descending
```

Answer (score 2):

The above Answers works fine. However in WIndows there is a alias called ls the same as on linux so another shorter command that works too would be `ls -Filter *.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Use **BaseName** for the file name without the file extension.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\*.js" | Sort-Object Length -Descending | ForEach-Object {
    $_.BaseName  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always used cygwin for this in the past.  My last employer locked down our environments and it wasn't available.  I like to review the latest files I've modified often.  I created the following environment variable named LatestCode to store the script.  I then execute it with: iex $env:latest code.

Here is the script:  get-childitem “.” -recurse -include *.ts, *.html , *.sass, *.java, *.js, *.css | where-object {$_.mode -notmatch “d”} |  sort lastwritetime -descending  | Select-Object -First 25 | format-table lastwritetime, fullname -autosize