# Search a specified path for multiple .xml files within the same folder

Tags: powershell

I am seeking help creating a PowerShell script which will search a specified path for multiple .xml files within the same folder.

1. The script should provide the full path of the file(s) if found.
2. The script should also provide a date.

Here's my code:

```
$Dir = Get-ChildItem C:\windows\system32 -Recurse
#$Dir | Get-Member
$List = $Dir | where {$_.Extension -eq ".xml"}
$List | Format-Table Name
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Please [edit] your question and add what happens when you run it and what did you expect to happen instead.

Comment: if you want all of the files under the folder, you may well do to add a `-recurse` to get all of the xml files.

Comment: What about your code doesn't do what you want? What result were you expecting? What result did you get? Also, what do you mean by "should provide a date"? Would `Get-ChildItem 'C:\windows\system32' -Filter '*.xml' -Recurse | Select-Object -Expand FullName` suffice?

Answer (score 0):

```
$folder = "C:\Windows\System32"
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File -Include "*.xml" | Select Name, FullName, LastWriteTime
```

This will return all xml files only and display the file name, full path to the file and last time it was written to.  The "-File" switch is only available in Powershell 4 and up.  So if doing it off a Windows 7 or Windows 2008 R2 Server, you will have to make sure you updated your WMF to 4 or higher.  Without file the second like will look like.

```
#Powershell 2.0
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Include "*.xml" | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Select Name, FullName, LastWriteTime
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the Select method mentioned above for the simpler syntax, but if for some reason you just want the file names with their absolute path and without the column header that comes with piping to Select (perhaps because it will be used as input to another script, or piped to another function) you could do the following:

```
$folder = 'C:\path\to\folder'
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Filter *.xml -File -Name | ForEach-Object { 
    [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($_) 
}
```

I'm not sure if Select lets you leave out the header.

You could also take a look at this answer to give you some more ideas or things to try if you need the results sorted, or the file extension removed:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31049571/10193624

Comment: `Select-Object -Expand FullName`

Comment: Ah nice. @AnsgarWiechers

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a few changes exporting the results to a .txt file, but though it provides the results I only want to isolate the same .xml files.

```
$ParentFolder = "C:\software"
$FolderHash = @{}

$Subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $ParentFolder

foreach ($EventFolder in $Subfolders) {
    $XMLFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $EventFolder.fullname -Filter *.xml*

    if ($XMLFiles.Count -gt 1) {
        $FolderHash += @{$EventFolder.FullName = $EventFolder.LastWriteTime}
    }
}

$FolderHash
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your self-answer you want a list of directories that contain more than one XML file without recursively searching those directories. In that case your code could be simplified to something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "${ParentFolder}\*\*.xml" |
    Group-Object Directory |
    Where-Object { $_.Count -ge 2 } |
    Select-Object Name, @{n='LastWriteTime';e={(Get-Item $_.Name).LastWriteTime}}
```