# Get recursively files with sizes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, fileinfo

I have

```
$postpst = ls $home_user\post | Measure-Object length -Sum | % {
        New-Object psobject -prop @{
            Name = "$home_user\post"
            Groesse = $(
                switch ($_.sum) {
                    { $_ -gt 1gb } { '{0:N2}GB' -f ($_ / 1gb); break }
                    { $_ -gt 1mb } { '{0:N2}MB' -f ($_ / 1mb); break }
                    { $_ -gt 1kb } { '{0:N2}KB' -f ($_ / 1Kb); break }
                    default { '{0}B ' -f $_ } 
                }
            )
        }
     }
$postpst
```

It shows only one file per user in the post dir, but not 2 or more. How can I get all?

I also tried:

```
$postpst = ls $home_user\post | Select-Object Name, @{Name="MegaBytes";Expression= {$_.Length / 1MB}}
$postpst
```

Here, I cannot format to Zero decimals.

My end result should be a recursive file list per user home dir with sizes searching for a specific extension (here pst files).

Here is my Code without sizes:

```
$pst= Get-ChildItem -Path $home_user -Filter *.pst -Recurse -File| Sort-Object Length -Descending | ForEach-Object{ $_.FullName}
```

I visited:

[How to retrieve recursively any files with a specific extensions in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049454/how-to-retrieve-recursively-any-files-with-a-specific-extensions-in-powershell/31049571)

Comment: Why is everything commented out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get-ChildItem will do what you want, you just need to fiddle with the output some.  You can do the whole thing in one line:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pst -Path  $home_user |
Sort-Object Length -Descending  |
Select-Object FullName, @{name='Size';expression={
  switch ($_.length) {
    { $_ -gt 1gb } { '{0:N2}GB' -f ($_ / 1gb); break }
    { $_ -gt 1mb } { '{0:N2}MB' -f ($_ / 1mb); break }
    { $_ -gt 1kb } { '{0:N2}KB' -f ($_ / 1Kb); break }
    default { '{0}B ' -f $_ }
  }
}}
```

Comment: you likely otta either _replace_ the `Format-*` cmdlet with `Select-Object`, OR add a comment that the output of your code is ONLY for final output to the screen or a plain text file. **_all the data has been  wrapped in formatting code & will fail in strange ways if one tries to use the data as normal objects._**

Comment: also, line-wrapping your code after each pipe would make it much  easier to read ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thanks Lee, good ideas.  Fixed up the formatting and changed Format-Table to Select-Object.

Comment: Thanks, how can I add a `filter` Parameter to get `*.pst`?

Comment: @Timo I edited the answer and added `-filter *.pst` to the Get-ChildItem command

Comment: I don't have PST files to look for so I used a different file type:
`PS DALTFC-1Q1YGH2 temp> Get-ChildItem -filter *.tdv -Path  $home_user |
>> Sort-Object Length -Descending  |
>> Select-Object FullName, @{name='Size';expression={
>>   switch ($_.length) {
>>     { $_ -gt 1gb } { '{0:N2}GB' -f ($_ / 1gb); break }
>>     { $_ -gt 1mb } { '{0:N2}MB' -f ($_ / 1mb); break }
>>     { $_ -gt 1kb } { '{0:N2}KB' -f ($_ / 1Kb); break }
>>     default { '{0}B ' -f $_ }
>>   }
>> }}

FullName             Size
--------             ----
C:\temp\test.tdv     1006B
C:\temp\file2.tdv    350B`

Comment: @Timo Not really sure how to format code in a comment. but you can see at the end I do have file sizes.

Comment: @Timo you didn't have recursion in your example, but do you need to add `-Recurse`  to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet?

Comment: @ScottHeath - very nice! fewer gotchas & much easier to read ... [*grin*]