# Filtered directory list not sorting similar to post included

Tags: powershell

Environment: Powershell 5.1  and Windows 10 Pro

Why is my list not sorting like showed in [StackOverflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31049571/139698).

**Bonus**: how to add the path to filename as well.

```
$res = Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.baml -Recurse -File -Name | Sort-Object Name
$res | ForEach-Object {
    [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_)
}
$res.Count
```

[image]

Comment: `Sort-Object Name` is incorrect, after using `-Name` you're dealing with an array of strings not with an array of objects which's property name is `Name`. It should have been just `| Sort-Object | ForEach...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to accomplish this would be to not use the `-Name` switch on [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.baml -Recurse -File | Sort-Object Name |
    Select-Object Name, DirectoryName
```

Above command would output objects, not strings, [`DirectoryName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.directoryname?view=net-6.0) would be the absolute path to the parent directory of each file.

As for why it's not currently sorting, after using the `-Name` switch, the output is an array of strings, only the **`Name` property Value of the files** is outputted hence sorting by the `Name` property is no longer possible (`Sort-Object Name`) since strings don't have a `Name` a property.